# how to use a join in cosmos db to get result

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have below structure

```
{
    "SubscriberId": "a4db02c1-f41b-4ab1-9f3e-83f9a7ccde83",
    "Subscription": {
        "Type": "Member",
        "MaxUsers": "200",
        "StartDate": "2018-07-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "EndDate": "2019-07-31T00:00:00.0000000Z",
        "Families": [
            {
                "Id": "4042e5dc-ff0e-5cca-d5ee-d96c4522f1db",
                "Products": [
                    {
                        "Id": "e9313211-ca18-4776-8fea-1d552b6f40d6",
                        "Price": null
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": "bf3cdaa4-8cbe-42e6-8f6f-20c1210dc4ac",
                        "Price": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "IsActive": "true"
    }
}
```

so I want to get data in the below structure, how can I use sql to do this?

```
SubscriberID ,  Type,Families.Id,Families.Products.Id, Families.Products.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use sql:

```
select distinct c.SubscriberId,c.Subscription.Type as Type,
f.Id as FamiliesId,p.Id as ProductsId,p.Price as ProductsPrice
from c
join f in c.Subscription.Families 
join p in f.Products
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: sorry for not replying on the answer , surely it helped me to great extent.

Comment: @Ranjith Great,would you please mark this answer to end this case?Thanks a lot.